# Как на ASP.NET 5 сделать Let’s Encrypt SSL сертификат с автообновлением?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, ssl, хостинг, letsencrypt

У меня есть Windows хостинг SmarterAsp и на нём сайт на ASP.NET MVC 5. На данный момент сайт работает по протоколу http, хочу перевести его на https.
Платить за сертификат пока не хочется, поэтому думаю это сделать на основе **Let’s Encrypt**.

Let’s Encrypt даёт сертификаты на 3 месяца, но предусматривает систему автообновления.

Реально ли, и если реально то как, сделать это в Windows Shared хостинге SmarterAsp .

Если не реально, какие есть другие варианты?

Comment: Это вообще слабо зависит от asp.net и от его версии. Сертификат контролируется iis, так что если хостер позволяет его задавать через api - вы сможете его поставить. Если нет - то нет.

Comment: @PashaPash А его автообновление тоже контролируется через IIS?

Comment: да, только косвенно, утилиты вроде letsencrypt win simple настраивают отдельное приложение для challenge, и до вашего приложения он не доходит. в общем, если ваш провайдер сам не поддерживает LE, то прикрутить его вручную достаточно тяжело

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо. Там ещё посмотрел что нужен свой чистый IP для этого дела, а у меня его нет, так что пока буду без этого.

Comment: Свой чистый IP необязателен, обычный http challenge должен и без него работать

Comment: @PashaPash Возможно это условие чисто smarterasp, но у них при попытке прикрутить свой сертификат через вебинтерфейс такую информацию выдаёт.